# How to use hostname passed as an argument in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have similar command to create container:

```
docker create --name=myname \
    --publish "80:80" \
    --hostname myhostname \
    local/local
```

And would like to use hostname for generating virtual host for web server.

I tried to used test command:

```
RUN touch ~/aaa-${HOSTNAME}
```

but got result: `aaa-719d8d68f3dc` but expected `aaa-myhostname`.

So, it uses intermediate container environment variable instead of passed one.

Comment: what is local/local, that is what image is your container based on?

Comment: @cantSleepNow, yeah, it's an image.

Comment: :) sure, but which one, ubuntu base? Fedora? something

Comment: @cantSleepNow, Ah, it's based on CentOS 7. :)

Comment: how about `cat /etc/hostname` ?

Comment: I don't about this one, I was trying a bit more complicated one: `sed -i "s:localhost:$(grep $(hostname) /etc/hosts | cut -f2  | cut -d' ' -f1):g" /path/to/file`. And it's always a hash.

Answer (score 0):

The --hostname option sets the container hostname, but not as an environment variable.

Use `-e hostname=my.host.name` instead of --hostname if you would like it to be accessible as a environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Anything in a `RUN` instruction happens inside an intermediate container, so if you create state which depends on the host information, what gets saved in the image layer is information about the intermediate container.

Anything that varies with each container should be done in the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`, so it will execute when the container runs. You could have a bootstrap script as your entrypoint, which sets up the state from the host and then runs your app process.